# AngularJS and SVG--using ng-click on a <rect> element?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

Problem: I want to run the `test` function when I click on a `<path>` element in an SVG graphic. Right now nothing happens when I click the element. HOWEVER--when I replace `ng-click` with `onclick="alert('success')"` the alert works fine. Any suggestions?

In my code...

section of my html...

```
<div ng-controller="converter">
  <embed src="/image.svg">
  <!--This button successfully runs the test function-->
  <button ng-click="test()">Test</button>
</div>
```

my app.js...

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('converter', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.test = function(){
        console.log("this click event is working");
    }
}]);
```

part of my embedded SVG file...

```
<rect id="e1-1-2" data-name="e1-1" class="cls-35" x="14" y="106" width="57" height="22" ng-click="test()"/>
```

(Here's the full code, for those interested: https://github.com/cwklausing/angular_guitar)

Comment: You added `ng-click` in `rect` element & `button` element

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA, and what is wrong?

Comment: try insert svg directly, instead with using _embed_

Comment: @Grundy it's nothing wrong but my question is will it be `ng-click` in both element?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA: The `button` is just a test to make sure there isn't a problem with the angular. It's non-essential to the problem.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA, you just missed `?`, so your comment, seems, not a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it inside a svg

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" ng-click="test()" />
</svg>
```

Here is the working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/M1Bs1AYtoIYrRALIz8XN?p=preview)

Comment: This link seems to didn't work. You didn't wrap the `rect` with `svg` in this link.

Comment: @MoshFeu it does work, can you just check the console and alert

Comment: @Sajeetharan: My rect was already wrapped in an svg, I just didn't include it. Mine still doesn't work; however, your example is extremely instructive, so I'll examine it more and hopefully find an answer.

Comment: @cwk.webdesign probably if you can post your code, wil try to help

Comment: @Sajeetharan - would github work? I'll post the link.

Comment: Here's the full code: [angular_guitar](https://github.com/cwklausing/angular_guitar)